# What is the best android emulator?

Tags: android, windows-7, virtualization

I am trying to install an android emulator for my mobile device browser testing. I tried with Google Android emulator, Bluestacks and GenyMotion. But all these three have some problems with it,

- Google Android Emulator - Chrome browser is not working
- Bluestacks - Does not have different versions of android OS
- GenyMotion - Intel Graphics driver does not support

  Is there any replacement for this?

My requirements:

- Emulator which can run a virtual device with different version of android (as in android SDK)
- Chrome browser should be working in the emulator

Comment: Chrome is not working on GenyMotion.

Comment: I cannot give you a direct recommendation due to lack of experience (I'm not using Windows), but be welcome to see my list of [Emulators](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators) (scroll to the end of the page for emulators running on PC). I myself used the Android-x86 inside VirtualBox for a while, which worked quite well.

Comment: You could try a emulator, it might not work, but APKOnline might work. There are a lot of ads, though...